# Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect while trying to connect Selenium Grid Node to Selenium Grid Hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I was trying to create a hub node connection in two Win 10 systems, so I downloaded Selenium Standalone Server 3.141.59 in both systems and in one system I typed:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
```

So I got the below output:

```
22:04:20.353 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
22:04:20.504 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
2019-12-30 22:04:20.930:INFO::main: Logging initialized @900ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
22:04:21.729 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
22:04:21.731 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://192.xxx.xxx.x:4444/grid/register/
22:04:21.731 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://192.xxx.xxx.x:4444/wd/hub
```

After that in my node system(also Win 10), I used the command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Users\debuk\Downloads\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.xxx.xxx.x:4444/grid/register -port 7777
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
C:\Users\debuk\Downloads>java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Users\debuk\Downloads\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.xxx.xxx.x:4444/grid/register -port 7777
21:39:55.251 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
21:39:55.418 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 7777
2019-12-30 21:39:56.912:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2118ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
21:39:57.250 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
21:39:57.360 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 7777
21:39:57.360 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
21:39:57.716 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
21:40:19.059 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.Failed to connect to /192.xxx.xxx.x:4444
21:40:19.060 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.xxx.xxx.x:4444/grid/register
21:40:40.092 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Failed to connect to /192.xxx.xxx.x:4444
21:41:06.111 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to /192.xxx.xxx.x:4444
21:45:38.322 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Failed to connect to /192.xxx.xxx.x:4444
```

Both the cases I opened the cmd where standalone server is present.
Can anyone have any solution for this? I've tried with selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0 as well, also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting the node you can use below command:

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="**chromedriver path**" -jar **selenium3.14.jar(path)** -role node -nodeConfig **json file path**

Create a json file for the capabilities as follows:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [

    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 30,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "platform":"WINDOWS"
    }
  ],

  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 30,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://**ip of hub**",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
  }
```

This code works for me you can use this for other browser's as well you just need to change the browser name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any major issues in your commands. However you may like to consider 2 changes as follows:

- Replace `-role webdriver` with **`-role node`**
- Remove the *double quotes* around **`chromedriver.exe`**

---

### Detailed Steps

Ensure the following steps:

- Start the *Selenium Grid Hub*:

  ```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
  ```
- Logs generated:

  ```
  18:10:13.310 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
  18:10:13.618 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$5] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4444
  2020-01-02 18:10:14.605:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2136ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  18:10:15.504 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
  18:10:15.509 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register/
  18:10:15.510 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://192.168.1.125:4444/wd/hub
  ```
- Access the **Selenium Grid Console v.3.141.59** through the url `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`:

[image: SeleniumGridConsole]

- Start the *Selenium Grid Node*:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -port 7777 -hub http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register
  ```
- Logs generated:

  ```
  18:33:55.959 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
  18:33:56.112 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 7777
  2020-01-02 18:33:56.584:INFO::main: Logging initialized @983ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  18:33:56.913 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
  18:33:57.029 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 7777
  18:33:57.029 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
  18:33:57.195 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
  18:33:57.734 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.1.125:4444/grid/register
  18:33:57.856 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
  ```
- Access the **Selenium Grid Console v.3.141.59** again through the url `http://localhost:4444/grid/console` to view the registered node:

[image: SeleniumGridConsole_NodeRegistered]